# Setting up a multisite wordpress

Tags: multisite

I am trying to setup my wordpress installation with [multsite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) support and it's having issues resolving the domain. I followed the steps but I did not change the domain from the initial ip address during setup.

So, I changed the settings in the wp-config.php file as follows:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '111.111.111.111');
```

to

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mydomain.com');
```

and refreshed the page.

I am now getting a blank page when I try to access the site from `mydomain.com` but can still accesss the site through the ip address.

There is no actual setting to change the root domain in a wordpress multisite that I can see.

Any ideas why I am getting a blank page when I access my site from the domain name?

My end goal is to setup multi site support with subdomains(e.g. `subdomain.domain.com`) and http.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpMyAdmin to change the site URL in two locations in the wp_options table. The URL you enter will be the root domain.

Comment: I am not using phpMyadmin. I am hosting wordpress itself.

Comment: Use whatever database editor you have to edit those two rows in the wp_options table. phpMyAdmin is just a common way to edit databases.